# Responsive columns with fixed with elements

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am attempting to create a set of columns that degrades gracefully from three columns to one with css. Normally I'd be fine doing this, but the requirement is that the item in each column should stay fixed in size, and that the columns should have 16px of spacing in between them at all times.

Here is what I am looking for:

[image]

However, when I add a width property to my columns, the spacing in between them grows much larger. I am stumped on how to keep the columns the same as the screen changes sizes. I know that inevitably the smaller I go, I will have to change the column widths with a media query to get them to turn into two columns, and then one, so that's not a problem.

Here is a picture of what is happening with the spacing of the columns when I set a width on the columns:
[image]

Oh, and of course, here is the code, and a [codepen link](https://codepen.io/DZuz14/pen/QWgKdqM). I recommend running it full screen with the SO editor, because since I haven't done any responsive css, the columns just condense into one big block, and its hard to see what's going on.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 40px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.tile {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.col {
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="tile"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <div class="tile"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <div class="tile"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need the width property in the `col` class. Let the child element in them determine that (since they have to be fixed in size). Glue the columns together with justify-center and add a column-gap property of 16px to the `row` class. 

You don't need the margins on the `tile` classes too.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the final styles should look like, I think:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 40px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 16px;
}

.tile {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

I also edited the codepen here https://codepen.io/tobycodes/pen/xxrEgje.

The trick is `justify: center;` and `gap: 16px;`. You can read more about the `gap` property here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap. The property is a shorthand for `grid-gap` but works perfectly for flexbox.

Comment: This is pretty sweet. gap has support on most of the modern browsers, wish it had a little more, but I think this will do! I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: Okay, so this doesn't really fix the problem. I need to somehow at a certain breakpoint, reduce the colums to 2 at a time, then eventually when we get down to phone sized devices, stack these on top of eachother. That's why I was trying to use the .col class initially to handle breakpoints.

Comment: Well, that's fine. You can re-introduce the col class and do that. In my codepen (in the answer), I added a `flex-wrap` property that automatically stacks the tiles on each other when the screen size can no longer contain 3 or even 2 columns.

The answer actually solves your problem of **_"but the requirement is that the item in each column should stay fixed in size, and that the columns should have 16px of spacing in between them at all times"_**.

You can either set width on the column or its child, and it has to be a fixed width i.e no percentages. The .tile is the child in this case.

Comment: Please see this codepen https://codepen.io/tobycodes/pen/xxrEgje

Answer (score 0):

```
.tile {
  width: 300px;
}
```

remove **width** from tile class to tile width equals parent div width